# AWS DynamoDB Scan failing on iOS but works on Android

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDB as back-end database for my mobile app, and the schema etc are identical across Android & iOS. For a particular use-case, I have to perform a Scan, based on two attributes which are not indexed. For iOS Objective C, I am using the following code:

```
AWSDynamoDBScanExpression *scanExpression = [AWSDynamoDBScanExpression new];
    scanExpression.limit = [NSNumber numberWithInt:maxCount];
    scanExpression.filterExpression = @"#l = :location AND event = :event";
    scanExpression.expressionAttributeNames = @{@"#l":@"location"};
    scanExpression.expressionAttributeValues = @{@":location":location,
                                                 @":event":EVENT_TASTING};
```

Both location and event are Strings. EVENT_TASTING is a String constant. This scan keeps returning zero results, even though I have validated that for the provided entries I should be receiving the results. I use the following code in Android Java:

```
DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
        scanExpression.setLimit(maxCount);

        scanExpression.addFilterCondition("location",
                new Condition()
                        .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
                        .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(location)));
        scanExpression.addFilterCondition("event",
                new Condition()
                        .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
                        .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(Constants.EVENT_TASTING)));
```

The scan works as expected in Android. What needs to change in iOS to make it work there too? I updated iOS SDK to 2.3.6 but it has not made a difference. This is the only scan operation I am doing in my code.

Is there an error in my scanExpression for iOS? Is there a way I can use the Android-style syntax to make this work on iOS?

**Update**

I tried the following changes:

```
   AWSDynamoDBScanExpression *scanExpression = [AWSDynamoDBScanExpression new];
AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue *locationVal = [AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue new];
locationVal.S = location;
AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue *eventVal = [AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue new];
eventVal.S = EVENT_TASTING;
scanExpression.limit = [NSNumber numberWithInt:maxCount];
scanExpression.filterExpression = @"#l = :location AND event = :event";
scanExpression.expressionAttributeNames = @{@"#l":@"location"};
scanExpression.expressionAttributeValues = @{@":location":locationVal,
                                             @":event":eventVal};
```

But now I am getting an error:

```
 The request failed. Error: [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSDynamoDBErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={message=ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes for key :location, __type=com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from @YosukeMatsuda, I was able to fix this by calling Scan repeatedly until LastEvaluatedKey is empty. I am posting this as answer because unfortunately Mike's answer is not pointing out the correct issue and is misleading.

Here's how I changed the code in iOS:

```
// In a different method (for first call):
AWSDynamoDBScanExpression *scanExpression = // See code in original question

// In a new method that can be called recursively:
// DynamoDBObjectMapper scan:class-for-model expression:scanExpression
// continueWithBlock -> if (task.result):
AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
if (paginatedOutput.items.count != 0)
// Append the paginatedOutput.items to the cumulative array
else
// Replace the cumulative array with paginatedOutput.items
if (paginatedOutput.lastEvaluatedKey.count == 0) {
    // Scan is complete - handle results
} else {
    // Check if you have sufficient results
    // In my case I had asked for 25 results but was getting 39
    // So it doesn't seem to obey the scanExpression.limit value
    // If more results are needed, continue the scan
    [scanExpression setExclusiveStartKey:paginatedOutput.lastEvaluatedKey];
    // Call this method recursively
}
```

If there is a more elegant solution I'd love to hear it. But at least it works now.

Answer (score 0):

There are several differences between the Android code you're using and the ObjectiveC version.

1. in the Android Version you're using the older *Filter Condition* API while in the ObjectiveC you're using the more modern *Filter Expression* API; this doesn't necessarily make the newer one fail but it's just something to point out
2. in the case of ExpressionAttributeValues, the values for `location` and `event` that you're passing in should be of type `AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue *`, not strings; if you make this change your query will most likely start working.

I hope this answers your question but can't be certain because you only say *"this works as expected in Android - how can I make it work in iOS"* but you're not telling us what's broken.

Comment: As I mentioned: "This scan keeps returning zero results, even though I have validated that for the provided entries I should be receiving the results." And yes, I am using the older filter condition because Android supports it, but iOS doesn't.

Comment: You still need to provide how you are instantiating `location` and `event`. Also, [turn on the verbose logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html) and update the question with the request JSON.

Comment: Updated the question with output from verbose logging option. Both event and location are strings. The above output shows they are being set correctly. If I use the same values for event and location in a query using DynamoDB console, the scan returns the values successfully.

Comment: My apologies @Mike, I did not see #2 of your comment earlier for some weird reason (possibly because of a bout of stupidity). Making the change and testing now. Will update and accept if it works.

Comment: @Mike, I tried the suggestion but am probably making a rookie error. I did set locationVal.S to the string but am getting an invalid parameter error. Please see update to my question above. Thanks!

Comment: You are using DynamoDB Object Mapper. The OM and low-level `AWSDynamoDB` have different requirements for `expressionAttributeValues`. `AWSDynamoDB` expects `AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue` as a key while `AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper` expects it to be an actual value (e.g. `NSString`) as a key. In your case, `locationVal` and `eventVal` need to be `NSString`.

Comment: I was using location and event as NSString earlier. The scan request was going through without errors, but I was getting 0 results back in iOS. Identical scan request returns the requested amount of results (25) in Android.

Comment: @YosukeMatsuda can you suggest what else can I try? As I mentioned both event and location are NSString values for my scan query, it seems to be well-formed, but it is returning zero results.

Comment: I looked at your question edit history. The log you posted suggests that DynamoDB returned `LastEvaluatedKey` when you ran the scan request. This means it didn't finish the scan. You [need to keep scanning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-response-LastEvaluatedKey) until `LastEvaluatedKey` returns nothing. Once you got all of the results, you can compare them with the one from the Android SDK.